# gulp не собирается

Tags: node.js, gulp

Перешел с 32-разрядной Windows7 на 64-разрядную. + обновил nodejs до 10ки.

Проекты на gulp все как один поотваливались. Сборка не пишет файлы в директорию.

Долго думал, что причина в Windows и ее ограничением на запись в директорию (галочка Read Only).Решил, что дело не в Windows, а в ноде. Откатился до 8й версии - не помогло.

Отчаялся, и переустановил новую Windows. Не помогло.

Gulp стоял всегда 3й. Может с обновлением ноды обновиться до 4го галпа? Да и там уже и синтаксис обновился. Надо бы попробовать с ним.

В общем, привожу итоговый небольшой пример с неработающим кодом. Может что-то не то делаю? Почему же писать в директории не хочет????

```
E:\[WEB]\PROJECTS\test-project>node -v
v10.15.1

E:\[WEB]\PROJECTS\test-project>gulp -v
[15:31:29] CLI version 2.0.1
[15:31:29] Local version 4.0.0
```

Почитал - там и CLI какое-то новое, обновил

```
npm rm --global gulp
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, в папку prod ничего не попадает.
И вообще, ни в одном проекте не пишет gulp файлы, частенько выдавая 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что толком у меня не прогугливается.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, gulp перестал работать с файловыми путями, включающими квадратные скобки. `E:/[WEB]/` как было у меня.
Может быть, исправят... 
Здесь обсуждение.
https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2296